# SP 2010 Visual Webpart - How to get all documents in a folder and sort them by caml query?

Tags: development, document-library, caml-query, visual-web-part, caml

I am making a visual web part for sharepoint 2010. I have a `SPFolder` object and I want to get all items in it, but I want to sort it by a specific field. I want to do this by CAML query instead of using a view.

I am currently doing this by `return library.GetItemsInFolder(library.DefaultView, folder);`.
It doesn't seem to contain a parameter for a CAML query.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.folder.aspx).

```
SPQuery Query = new SPQuery();
Query.Folder = SPFolder Object;
Query.Query =  "insert caml query here..."
SPListItemCollection collListItems = List.GetItems(oQuery);
```

I would suggest doing some reading first before implementing this if you haven't used Spquery before.... You may want to look into the row limits and view attributes properties...